# How to push a new item to nested array in angular7

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

I have a nested array ,i want to push new item to nested array.

```
FoodNode= [
  {
    name: 'Fruit',
    parent:'root',
    children: [
      {name: 'Apple',parent:'Fruit'},
      {name: 'Banana',parent:'Fruit'},
      {name: 'Fruit loops',parent:'Fruit'},
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Vegetables',
    parent:'root',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Green',
        parent:'Vegetables',
        children: [

        ]
      }, {
        name: 'Orange',
        parent:'Vegetables',
        children: [         
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

Now i want to add it to childrens of green.

```
   this.fileElements.filter(res => {
      if (res.parent === 'root') {
        this.fileList.push(res);
      } else {
          this.fileList.filter((search, index) => {
          if (search.name === res.parent) {
            console.log(typeof search.children === 'undefined');
            search.children.push(res);
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

this code push the item to 1 level only (like immediate children),bases on parent value Im pushing element to the children.I'm using mat-tree so I need same structure.please help

Comment: Think of your nested JSON object as a tree. Now apply either DFS or BFS to find the node and apply modification accordingly

Comment: Note: this has to do nothing with angular7

Comment: I believe its not structured or systematic json and if you still want to manually add the element you can try something like, FoodNode[1].children[0].children.push('test');

Comment: @alokstar Its a dynamic data..

Comment: @Karthi "this code push the item to 1 level only" could you explain a bit more what you need it to do? Note: It seems to me that an organization of the json object could help you in the long run (if you have control over that).

Comment: I have done it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps.

```
this.FoodNode.forEach(e => {
   if (e.name == "Vegetables") {
   let abcd = e.children;
   abcd.forEach(e1 => {
   if (e1.name === "Green") {
      let data = [
          { name: "Apple" },
          { name: "Banana" },
          { name: "Fruit loops" }
      ];
      data.forEach(e2 => {
      e1["children"].push(e2);
    });
   }
});
}
});
```